# Weird UITableViewCell shadow when using custom background?

Tags: iphone

Ok. So, I want a custom background to my `tableview` so I used the following code:

```
[[self tableView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"red-background.png"]]];
```

or

```
[[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"red-background.png"]]];
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

but the end result is:
[image]

This really annoying and ugly.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try clear color for cell's background color.
or `[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];`

Comment: Sorry, realised it was clearColor not whiteColor! But still it does not work.

Comment: `UITableViewSeparatorStyleSingleLine.` try this. :)

Comment: @iApple that is the correct answer, but you should make it an answer so he can accept it rather than a comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

[image]Use this line,

```
  UITableViewSeparatorStyleSingleLine.
[tableProfile setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

This are changes I did in my app.

Comment: Nop, no luck :( I set it via IB and Code ([self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine])... What else could it be???

Comment: Making it single is the only solution and even it worked for me.

Comment: Ok so you currently have a black background according to me, try using  the following code:[[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red-background.png"]]]; Make sure you use a image. Try now.

Comment: I have used image for view and above it is my tableview with this properties.

Comment: Ok so the thing is that when I set the background of the table clear color the background goes black. Thanks for the help so far boss!

Answer (score 0):

Ok turned out the image was screwing up like that... Because i tried another image and it worked perfectly fine. Problem solved! Thank you very much iApple for your help and time!